# Reading file in the same folder - Improvement?

Tags: python, python-os

i am writing an python script.  I was having some problems to open the file.   The error was always that system just can not find the file.

Because of that i tried get the active path... Replace backslash ... and so on....

Is there any improvements to work with the file in the same folder?

### The Code

```
import os

# The name of the txt file that is in the same folder.
myFile = 'noticia.txt'

# Getting the active script
diretorio = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Replace BackSlash and concatenate myFile
correctPath = diretorio.replace("\\", "/") + "/" + myFile

# Open file
fileToRead = open(correctPath, "r")

# Store text in a variable
myText = fileToRead.read()

# Print
print(myText)
```

### Note:

The script is in the same folder of the txt file.

Comment: If it's in the same folder, you don't need any wizardry, just do `with open(myFile, 'r') as fileToRead:` (instead of doing `fileToRead = open(...)` as contextual opens are better since they close the file automatically, something you forgot here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any improvements to work with the file in the same folder?

First off, please see PEP 8 for standard conventions on variable names.

```
correctPath = diretorio.replace("\\", "/") + "/" + myFile
```

While forward slashes are preferred when you specify a new path in your code, there is no need to replace the backslashes in a path that Windows gives you. Python and/or Windows will translate behind the scenes as necessary.

However, it would be better to use `os.path.join` to combine the path components (something like `correct_path = os.path.join(diretorio, my_file)`).

```
fileToRead = open(correctPath, "r")

# Store text in a variable
myText = fileToRead.read()
```

It is better to use a `with` block to manage the file, which ensures that it is closed properly, like so:

```
with open(correct_path, 'r') as my_file:
    my_text = my_file.read()
```

Comment: thanks to share your knowledge.  I am reading [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as you mention...

Comment: if i use ```with``` block to manage file.... as you mention...  i still have to use ```my_file.close()```?  Thanks

Comment: No, that's what the block is for.